# On Car Tire Balancing in Automatic Cars

Tags: automatic-transmission, wheel-balance

Will doing "On Car Tire Balancing" for balancing wheels of Automatic transmissions cars cause any issues to the transmission?

You can see an [On-Car balancer in this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UP97bO-MpU).

Comment: This question is very vague, and it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - I think they're asking about [on car tire balancing](https://youtu.be/7UP97bO-MpU) with the tire on the car, but doing so with an automatic transmission versus doing it with a manual transmission.

Comment: in Automatic Transmission You Should not using car in Neutral For Towing or etc... So is this mean that we can't use On Car tire balancing?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, Thanks.  I didn't know there was such a thing.  I envisioned the car wheel balancing itself as you drove down the road.

Comment: I don't think for the short amount of time you would run the balancer that any harm would come to the transmission.

Comment: @agentp, makes sense.  Saidh, take a look at [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/22278/12030) for more on why you can't tow an automatic in neutral.  Doesn't seem like a tire balancer would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The on-car balancers (some anyway) can spin the wheels up to 80mph - so for an auto box, I would advise use a shop with an off-car balancer to avoid any issue.

Comment: But, just one wheel spining and other wheel is on floor when you use On-Car balancer.  so the speed will be 1/2 in Transmission because Differential.

Comment: The gear connected to the drive shaft and wheel will be doing the same speed as the wheel and then the differential will increase the speed into the transmission :  what do you think the final drive ratio does???

Comment: i think when the Drive shaft spin X rpm, wheels has X rpm Speed.  But the speed of wheel will be 2X when one of the wheels stoped and other spining. when your car trap in muds or snow and just one of the wheels spins, the speed of that Wheel is 2*Speedometer.

Comment: Check how a differential works.

Comment: @SolarMike - said h is absolutely right. With only one wheel spinning, it will reduce the speed of the driveshaft by 1/2 ... how do you think a differential works?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 surely the wheel rpm is the same as the driveshaft rpm?